# Is this rule a consistent estimator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, means, law-of-large-numbers

Define the sample mean $S_n=(X_1+...+X_n)/n$ of a sequence $\{X_1,...,X_n,...\}$ of i.i.d. random variables with non-negative discrete support, known mean $0<\mu<1$, finite standard deviation $\sigma$, and no probability on $\infty$.  Results like the law of large numbers tell us that for a sequence of indices $n_1< ... <n_j<...$, where for example $n_1=1,n_2=2,...,n_j=j,...$ , that the sequence of sample means ${S_{n_1},...,S_{n_j},...}\xrightarrow{p}\mu$.

Now consider the subsequence of indices $n_{j_1}< ... <n_{j_k}<...$,  consisting of all $n_{j_k}$ in the original sequence such that $n_{j_k}$'s associated set $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_{n_{j_k}}\}$ meets the following condition: 
 $X_1+X_2+...+X_{n_{j_k}} < n_{j_k}$.  Does ${S_{n_{j_1}},...,S_{n_{j_k}},...}\xrightarrow{p}\mu$?

Comment: Why $1+n_{j_k}$? I would have thought that it would work just as well with $X_1+X_2+...+X_{n_{j_k}} < n_{j_k}$?

Comment: lol i guess there is no difference analytically

Comment: I think actually it is impossible to know as stated... i should have written if and only if so that every value that meets that is included, or we flip a coin whenever the condition is met to determine whether to include it. Without something like that we could construct a sequence that is artificially guaranteed to diverge...so assume i think every index that satisfies the property is in the subsequence

Comment: updated the question to address the above comments: removed the -1, and tried to make it clear that the subsequence is all elements of the original sequence that satisfy that property

Comment: Is the choice of $n_{j_1}< ... <n_{j_k}<...$ assumed to be independent of $\omega$?

Comment: @Davide Giraudo, if $\omega$ is meant to be an event, then I think we are talking about $X_1,...,X_n,...$ and the subsequence is defined by it.  So it would have to be dependent on that even, since the event dictates the sequence.